Custom signet without importprivkey
To deploy a custom signet miner the instructions at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Signet rely on the deprecated importprivkey rpc method.
Is there an alternative approach so that the private key can be seeded or imported so https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/signet/miner script can still be used?

In the end I just enabled legacy wallets with the setting below:
deprecatedrpc=create_bdb

It would still be good to know if a custom signet can be enabled with Bitcoin Core's default HD wallets.
